# xamarin Application Failed To Deploy in Visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, deployment, xamarin

I tried more to run my Xamarin Application. It builds successfully but when trying to debug, the following ecxceptions are risen.

As I understand there is some missed packages because

> Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?

message is displayed below the deployment status message.

**Debug output**

```
1>_PrimaryCpuAbi=armeabi-v7a
1>Detecting installed packages...
1>Target device is armeabi-v7a.
1>Installing the Mono shared runtime (debug - 1466176850)...
1>10% ... 3776kb of 37460kb copied
1>20% ... 7552kb of 37460kb copied
1>30% ... 11264kb of 37460kb copied
1>40% ... 15040kb of 37460kb copied
1>50% ... 18752kb of 37460kb copied
1>60% ... 22528kb of 37460kb copied
1>70% ... 26240kb of 37460kb copied
1>80% ... 30016kb of 37460kb copied
1>90% ... 33728kb of 37460kb copied
1>100% ... 37460kb of 37460kb copied
1>:Deployment failed
1>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
1>
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
1>System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
1>
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__99.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>d__98.MoveNext()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
1>   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.InstallPackageAssemblies.Execute()
1>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
1>---> (Inner Exception #0) Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
1>
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__99.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>d__98.MoveNext()<---
1>`enter code here`
1>Done building project "App1.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>Build FAILED.
1>
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: @sham same here.. where any of you able to solve it??

Comment: @fabricio I was not able to resolve this issue.

Comment: @sham I think what I did was to uninstall the application from my phone.. you'll need to go to "All" or "Running" tab and uninstall the "com.yourapplication" package (there is an adb command for uninstalling apk that I didn't use, but it could come in handy for you)

Comment: Java JDK
Download the Java JDK v1.7.0 installer to any directory on your disk, double-click the downloaded file and follow the on-screen instructions.

It is very important to install the 32-bit version of Java JDK even if you're using 64-bit Windows. It is also important that Java JDK v1.6 is installed (although it is fine to have Java JDK 1.7 or newer installed at the same time).     Download the Android NDK for Windows version r10e to any directory on your disk and double-click it to start the NDK installation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ARM based emulators (I had the same issue)?

If yes then those are very slow and the application cannot be deployed until those are started.

Use x86 based emulators, these are not so fast but atleast bearable.

In any case (x86 or ARM) start your emulator first and wait until you see the home screen.